# Как получить часть данных из state в Pinia.js

Tags: vue.js

Пробую pinia.js, и столкнулся с непонятным мне поведением:
Имею такой стор:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'
import axios from 'axios'
export const usePostStore = defineStore('posts', {
    state: () => ({posts:null }),
    getters: {
      
    },
    actions: {
      async getPosts() {
        await axios
        .get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts`)
        .then(response => (this.posts = response.data));
      },
    },
  })
```

И все приходит и попадает в posts.
В компоненте получаю:

```js
<script setup>
import { usePostStore } from '@/store/post.js'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'

const store = usePostStore()
store.getPost()

</script>

<template>
    {{ store.post.userId }}
</template>
```

Вопрос: почему при выводе {{ store.post}} у меня выводится без ошибок, а при попытке вывести например титл = {{ store.post.title}} - cannot read properties of null (reading 'title')

Comment: getPost - ассинхронный, при выводе постов делайте проверку: {{ store.post && store.post.userId }}

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это и есть ответ на мой вопрос